# sort images by how detailed they are

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm looking for a Java package that allow me to sort images by how detailed they are. I would like to create a service that will scan images and filter out the non-interesting images. I'm aware that there is no absolute way of doing it but I would like to make the best effort.

Thanks!

Comment: What? No, seriously, this question is like asking "how can I sort snacks by how tasty they are, using a teapot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `opencv` which is quite powerful library to play with images.

Here is a sample algorithm for you.

```
Convert your image from RGB to GrayScale image. 

Sum color of your image pixel by pixel// there was a sum() method that automatically sums.

Divide the result to numPixel(=height*width)//there may be methods like mean()

Get the standard deviation of the pixels// if stdDev > thresh then it is "interesting image"
```